# Python "penup()"

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am creating a frieze pattern for a uni assignment. So I need to repeat the pattern 4 times. When I move on to starting the next pattern, I use penup(), however it's lifting the pen in the previous pattern which I had completed.

Here's the code:

```
from turtle import *

#Draw four basic elements
#Draw a basic element
for spokes in range (1, 7):
    forward(50)
    penup()
    goto(0,0)
    left(36)
    pendown()

#move to start of next basic element
    penup()
    forward(125)
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Thanks! :)

I need to have 125 units between the first and second pattern.

Comment: You do a `penup` at the end of each iteration; why *wouldn't* it be "lifting the pen in the previous pattern"?

Comment: Draw your pattern physically on paper by following your own code. Make note of each change in direction or lift/down. Do not lift your own hand unless your code says so

Comment: What's the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is that you call `pendown()` *after* you draw your shape, not before. You need to do:

```py
from turtle import *

for spokes in range (1, 7):
    pendown()
    forward(50)
    penup()
    goto(0,0)
    left(36)

    # move to start of next basic element
    penup()
    forward(125)
```

---

N.B.
I would change your code like:

```py
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle() # create turtle instance to avoid confusion

for i in range(6): # for loop just runs the same code 6 times
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(50)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(0,0)
    t.left(36)

    t.penup()
    t.forward(125)

turtle.mainloop() # keep window open
```

This new code gives the output:

[image: output]

(I assume that's what you want.)